# Как запустить jar файл из командной строки? Сборка Maven

Tags: java, maven

C:>java -jar traprange-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar -h

Командная строка выдает: 
no main manifest attribute, in traprange-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar

pom.xml

```
<build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <mainClass>traprange.MAIN</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                    <descriptorRefs>
                        <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                    </descriptorRefs>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

Главный класс:

```
package traprange;

import org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

public class MAIN {
    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MAIN.class);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        PropertyConfigurator.configure(MAIN.class.getResource("/traprange/log4j.properties"));

        if (args.length == 1 && "-h".equals(args[0])) {
            printHelp();
        }
    }

    private static void printHelp() {
        StringBuilder help = new StringBuilder();
        help.append("Argument list: \n");

        logger.info(help.toString());
    }

}
```

Что не так?

Comment: какой командой собираете?

Comment: В Eclipse run as -> Maven clean потом run as -> Maven install

Answer (score 2, accepted):

с вашей конфилгурацией плагина собирать `jar` надо такой командой

```
mvn clean compile assembly:single
```

Либо поменять конфигурацию и добавить

```
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <id>make-assembly</id>
      <phase>package</phase>
      <goals>
        <goal>single</goal>
      </goals>
    </execution>
  </executions>
```

после закрытия тега `</configuration>`

Comment: Спасибо. Да надо Maven учить.